# How to store opened canister of butane?

Tags: kitchen-safety, gas

I opened a canister of butane last night to cook, and it's now half empty. What is a safe place to store it? Can I leave the canister in the stove? (note - stove is disengaged)  Or do I have to take it out and put the cap back on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about this kind of cannister:

[image: generic 225g butane cannister]

Then disengage it, but you can leave it stored in the stove.  That's probably the best place for it.

Comment: Yes that's what I was referring to. I wasn't sure if leaving it in the stove would cause it to leak since it's horizontal. But seems like the answer is that it's fine as long as it's disengaged. Thanks

Comment: YW!  If this is your answer, you shoudl select it.

Answer (score 1):

Butane canisters come in a great variety of size, from small camping canisters to 15kg household canisters and even larger ones, for supplying a whole building with gas.

Since you mentioned your canister is half empty after cooking a meal, we are talking most likely about a camping size canister with 2-3kg.

You don't have to dismount the stove from the canister, specially if you plan to use it again soon. In case you plan no further usage, I'd suggest to dismount the stove as it has a great surface to tear and could cause an unsafe connection between canister and stove.

Anyway, leaking gas causes great danger, canisters could eventually explode. Therefore make sure:

- the storage place is sufficiently ventilated
- there is no direct sunlight
- nor flames, sparks, smoking nearby
- not near a heating device
- storage place is out of children reach
- canister is in an upright position